# Fail to link UniDAQ library with MinGW4.8.2 in Qt5 (undefined reference to `_imp__)

Tags: c++, qt, linker, mingw

I am trying to use a Digital I/O PCI card (Data Aquisition Board PISO-P32A32U) and I am struggeling with the implementation of the library file, despite having read through lots of related topics.

My system is running on Windows 7 (64-bit) and I am programming with Qt5.3.1 using the MinGW4.8.2 compiler.

I included the UniDAQ.h to my project, added `LIBS += "D:\myProject\debug\UniDAQ.lib"` to my .pro-file and placed the UniDAQ.lib as well as the UniDAQ.dll in the debug folder of myProject.

Nevertheless, when trying to call a function of the library, I get an error message like

> undefined reference to `_imp__Ixud_SearchCard@8'

Since the header-files is stating

> Support Language: Visual C++/Visual C.NET/Borland C++ Builder

I am now assuming that the library was built with and for MSVC and is not compatible linking with Qt/MinGW. 
Could that be the case? 
If so: Is there some kind of workaround to implement the library?

I am thankful for any piece of advice.

Comment: *Is there some kind of workaround to implement the library?* If you have the source files you could compile the lib with cmake

Comment: Unfurtunately I only have the .dll, .lib and .h files from the manufacturer. As an extra information: Same error with qmake and cmake.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to link 64-bit *.lib file to a 32-bit project or vice versa. There are two versions of UniDAQ.lib file included in UniDAQ's distributable (64- and 32-bit), try to use another one.